# How to get nextState in canDeactivate functional guard?

Tags: angular

As seen on Angular documentation, class based route guards are deprecated in favor of functional guards. So what would be the equivalent of getting next state to below deprecated class based guard?

```
canDeactivate(
  component: SomeComponent,
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
  nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  if (nextState.url.includes('/error')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I understand ActivatedRouteSnapshot and RouterStateSnapshot are passed when guard is invoked, but the RouterStateSnapshot only have the current state.

```
export const canDeactivateGuard = (
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshotstate
): boolean => {
  if (nextState.url.includes('/error')) { // How do I get the next state?
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

This is how canDeactivate guard is registered in the module.

```
{
  path: 'somePath',
  component: SomeComponent,
  canDeactivate: [canDeactivateGuard]
}
```

router.navigate('/error') is called inside SomeComponent's ngOnInit() and I was hoping canDeactivate guard can get the next state's URL so that I can check the condition.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the angular documentation, you can get access to the nextState using the new functional approach like this.

```
type CanDeactivateFn<T> = (component: T, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState: RouterStateSnapshot) => Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree;
```

https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivateFn

Hope that helps!